# Composer update fails while updating the composer

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4

$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack dev-master requires anahkiasen/rocketeer ^2.2 -

> no matching package found.
>       - anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack dev-master requires anahkiasen/rocketeer ^2.2 -
>   no matching package found.
>       - Installation request for anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack dev-master -> satisfia
>   ble by anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack[dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion f
or more details.

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further commo
n problems.

Comment: "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "way/generators": "~2.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "1.*",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "2.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "1.*",
        "anahkiasen/underscore-php": "1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~1.8",
        "anahkiasen/rocketeer": "2.0.*@dev",
        "anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack": "dev-master",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
        "bradleyboy/laravel-braintree": "dev-master"

    },

Comment: "anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack": "2.0.*@dev",   instead of "anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack": "dev-master",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Changed to "anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack": "2.0.*@dev",  instead of
"anahkiasen/rocketeer-slack": "dev-master",

Answer (score 0):

Add in anahkiasen/rocketeer as an explict dependancy with the @dev tag

eg

```
"anahkiasen/rocketeer": "^2.2@dev"
```

The issue is that you are not configured to accept dev packages (which you should leave as is).

This way, your default can be to only accept stable, but you can selectively include packages with dev stability as required

Comment: I changed but the following error is coming.

Comment: Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install nesbot/carbon 1.20.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1

Comment: please update your question rather than paste this stuff here. You might want to put your full composer.json file into pastebin or similar

Comment: In composer.json file contains

Comment: "anahkiasen/rocketeer": "2.0.*@dev",

Comment: I did change and composer  updated as "anahkiasen/rocketeer": "^2.2@dev"

Comment: ok - it looks like your original issue is resolved and you now have other issues. Impossible to say without seeing your composer.json file.